# Password in confirm box Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Delete button in my PHP page which deletes a record.
But when I delete that button I do a confirm box with:

```
<form action="log.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
```

Can I make it so when they confirm they have to fill in a password?

So what I mean is something like this

```
<form action="log.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('password :');">
```

And then they have to fill in a password

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @guest271314 How does that work?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just read some tutorials on authentication, roles and permissions for web sites.

Comment: @roullie What do you mean by that?

Comment: @bIgBoY I meant Instead of the Are you sure there comes a box with "password:" and then they fill in the correct password to delete the record

Comment: Why dont u write a jquery function on form submit ....

Comment: @AminKodaganur What sort of jquery function do you mean?

Comment: just give a id to form and on submit event do the  confirm thing if says yes then promt for password ...

Comment: @Emre `var pass = prompt("Pass", ''); alert('Your pass is ' + pass )`

Comment: Don't recommend `prompt()` for password values, it shows publicly

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude What is better then prompt then?

Comment: Use a `<div>` with fixed positioning with a `<input type="password">` inside, it's better. If you ask a user for his password in a `prompt()` it shows on screen. It's insecure, false password and it can't be encrypted. Don't use `prompt()` for passwords, are not maded for this.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I want a Popup when the button is pressed to let them confirm with a password. But not with a input type password.

Comment: Have you the passwords in the server or are hardcoded into the javascript?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It's just in the javascript. When I check page source I just see it there.

Comment: I can't help you better. Write passwords inside javascript files is insecure and very dangerous. The best that I can recommend you is to make a php file with the passwords (if you don't have a database) and control it via AJAX functions. jQuery can help you to make this task easy.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for sticking here and replying to me all the time I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You Need some thing like this, Modify according to your requirements

```
<script>
function do_check()
{
    var return_value=prompt("Password:");
    if(return_value==="your_password")
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
</script>
<form action="log.php" method="post" onsubmit="return do_check();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`input type="password"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) , `required` attribute` ; disable submit until password set

```js
document.forms["form"].querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
  this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input type="button" value="Are you sure?" />
  <input type="password" minlength="3" maxlength="7" required disabled />
  <input type="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.forms["form"].querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
  this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
  <input type="button" value="Are you sure?" />
  <input type="password" minlength="3" maxlength="7" required disabled />
  <input type="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, provide more details on why your code will work and why you chose this method to fix the issue.